# Render container conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible to render container for a template based on condition with `knockout.js`?

This does not work, but shows what i want to do:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
 <!-- ko if: $data.startContainer -->
 <div class="container">
 <!-- ko -->

 <div data-bind="html: $data.contentElement"></div>

 <!-- ko if: $data.endContainer -->
 </div>
 <!-- ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, your list will begin to render before the container. At some point the elements will start to be rendered inside the container. After another position of the list is reached, the elements will begin to render after the container. Is that right? If thats the goal, have you considered 3 foreachs with computed lists of the elements before, inside and after respectively?

Comment: Yes, you are right.
3 foreache's might be an option, but real case is much more complex and hard to change, i'm interested if knockout templating is flexible enough to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a thread on knockout.js github site that indicates this as **not possible with the native templating** model:
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/307

Apparently, the closing comment is understand as internal to the not closed div tag.

My hopes were on the dynamic templates, but failed also like shown in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/XbdGs/3/

```
<script type="text/html" id="withContainer">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- ko template: 'withoutContainer' -->
         <!-- /ko -->
     </div>
</script>
```

From that i conclude you can try the 3 foreachs solution, use Posthuma suggestion or fallback to another templating engine like jquery.tmpl or Underscore as mentioned on knockout documentation.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through a custom binding.

**Update:**

If you want to open a div and close from another item, the custom binding would look like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomBinding = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context){
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var currentElement = element;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function(item){
        if(item.startContainer){
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            $(container).append(item.displayContent);                
            $(container).addClass("container");
            currentElement = container;                
        }
        else if(item.endContainer){
            $(currentElement).append(item.displayContent);
            $(element).append(currentElement);
            currentElement = element;
        }
        else{                
            $(currentElement).append(item.displayContent);
        }            
    });
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind='myCustomBinding: items'></div>
```

There are probably better ways to write this code and possibly use knockouts built-in bindings, but this should be enough to get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/posthuma/f5wG4/2

Comment: Thank you, but not what i needed. I need to wrap some of the elements in one container, not each of them in it's own one. That's why in my snippet i have different bindings for opening and closing container